# rsyslog block by dns

Tags: dns, blocking, syslog

rsyslog version is 5.8.6

The rsyslog client send message to remote server by udp， the remote server is used by domain,  when the domian can't resolv and **timeout**, the rsyslog will be blocked.

I add the domain to `/etc/hosts`, and restart rsyslogd, that will be ok.

I haven't configed main queue and use the default configuration, I think the reason maybe the queue was blocked, but I could'n find the real reason.

Is anyone know?